# Can I have a program with 2 sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

This is a simple chat program in Java. I know I can get the work done by 1 socket but I was wondering why not use 2 sockets?

This executes but does not work as intended. Kindly see the code and find the error. Please help me as i am new to this.
Server code is below.

### Server.java

```
    import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;
        public class server {
        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(10001);
        Socket s=ss.accept();
        Socket s1=new Socket("localhost",10005);
        DataInputStream di=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dot=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str1="",str="";
        while(str1!="exit"){
            str=(String)di.readUTF();
            System.out.println("message="+str);
            System.out.println("Enter message:");
            str1=br.readLine();
            dot.writeUTF(str1);
            dot.flush();
        }
        di.close();
        dot.close();
        s1.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();


    }

}
```

---

Client code is below kindly tell the problem.
i know i can get the work done by 1 socket but i was trying why not use 2 sockets.

### Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class client {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            ServerSocket ss;
            ss = new ServerSocket(10005);
            Socket s=ss.accept();
            Socket s1=new Socket("localhost",10001);
            DataInputStream di=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dot=new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String str="",str1="";
            while(str1!="exit"){
                System.out.println("Enter message:");
                str1=br.readLine();
                dot.writeUTF(str1);
                dot.flush();
                str=(String)di.readUTF();
                System.out.println("message="+str);
            }
            dot.close();
            di.close();
            s1.close();
            ss.close();
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the error is, what is not working and why do you think 2 sockets will solve it?

Comment: Why you used ServerSocket class in client side?

Comment: just seeing that if i send from 1 socket and listen from 1 socket in one program. and in the same way send from 1 socket and listen from 1 in another program.

Comment: 'Does not work as intended' is not a problem description. *Of course* you can use 2 sockets in Java, or 200,000, depending on what your platform allows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open (within reason) as many sockets as you want from a single JVM.

The problem with your code that you're using a *blocking* API, meaning that the thread doesn't return from the call `br.readLine()` and so it cannot do any more work (including waiting for data on other sockets).

You've got a couple of options:

1. create a thread per socket (being careful of resource limitations).
2. use the [NIO API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)) that is inherently non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you will need to fix to make your program work:

1. Both server and client passively open a socket first and then both wait for the other one to connect first (`ss.accept()`). Solution: In client.java, move the the line `ss.accept()` below the active open `Socket s1=new Socket("localhost",10001);`.
2. The server uses socket `s` for input and output. You probably want to use `s1` as output. Solution: In server.java, in the line `DataOutputStream dot=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());`: replace `s` with `s1`.

Please let me know if the program now works as expected.

For your future experiments, you might want to have a look at [this tutorial on NIO selectors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) or threaded network application models, as Nick Holt suggested.

Comment: no expection occurs: Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Comment: Make sure you didn't start multiple instances of either the client or the server. If this problem stays, change the port numbers that you use in both the client and the server to other values.